# Bootstrap animated navbar with different sized logos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to animate a bootstrap navbar. When the page loads you see the full size logo and when you scroll down the navbar decreases in size and a smaller logo fades in. Got that far but i'm having trouble with a glitch that can end up with both the logos being in view if you scroll down a little and then quickly scroll back up. So i'm looking for a best way to make sure there is only one logo at any given time. here's my jQuery:

```
var header_closed = false;
var header_open = true;
var timer;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (timer) {
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 20 && header_closed === false) {
            header_closed = true;
            header_open = false;
            $('.biglogo').fadeOut("fast", function() {
                $('.navbar-header').animate({
                    height: "54px"
                }, 250, function() {
                    $('.smllogo').fadeIn(500);

                });
            });


        } else if ($(document).scrollTop() < 20 && header_open === false) {
            header_open = true;
            header_closed = false;
            $('.smllogo').fadeOut(500, function() {
                $('.navbar-header').animate({
                    height: "138px"
                }, 250, function() {
                    $('.biglogo').fadeIn('fast');
                });
            });
        }
    }, 200);
});
```

The html is just a normal bootstrap fixed navbar with two navbar-brands (the small logo has a display: hidden; to hide it from view on load.. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you change the img source during your animation?  This would mean they could never both be displayed:

```
if ($(document).scrollTop() > 20 && header_closed === false) {
            header_closed = true;
            header_open = false;
            $('.logo').fadeOut("fast", function() {
                $('.navbar-header').animate({
                    height: "54px"
                }, 250, function() {
                    $('.logo').attr('src','small.jpg');
                    $('.logo').fadeIn(500);

                });
            });
} else if ($(document).scrollTop() < 20 && header_open === false) {
            header_open = true;
            header_closed = false;
            $('.logo').fadeOut(500, function() {
                $('.navbar-header').animate({
                    height: "138px"
                }, 250, function() {
                    $('.logo').attr('src','big.jpg');
                    $('.logo').fadeIn('fast');
                });
            });
        }
    }, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently did the same thing in one of my project you may have a quick look here: http://musichighcourt.com/soundcloudapp

I'm sharing the jquery code and the css I have used for the same.

**HTML**

```
    <header>
        <div id="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" class="logo img-responsive"></div>
        <div id="nav" class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://musichighcourt.com/soundcloudapp/top-charts.php">Top Charts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tips</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                <li><a href="user_login.php">Login|Signup</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100){  
        $('header').addClass("sticky");
        $('#nav').addClass("sticky-menu");
        $('#logo').children('img').addClass("sticky-logo");
    }
    else{
        $('header').removeClass("sticky");
        $('#nav').removeClass("sticky-menu");
        $('#logo').children('img').removeClass("sticky-logo");
    }
});
```

Change the value of scroll in this line according to your convenience: `($(this).scrollTop() > 100)`

**CSS**

```
/*header */
header{
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
    font-size:16px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:'ubuntu' , sans-serif;
    transition:.5s;
    z-index:1000;
}

.sticky {
  font-size:14p;
  height: 50px;
  background: #171515;
}

#logo{
    float:left;
}

.logo{
    height:50px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:30px;
    transition:.3s;
}

.sticky-logo{
    margin:0px;
    padding:2px;
}

/* menu */

.menu{
    padding:24px;
    float:right;
    transition:.3s;
}

.sticky-menu{
    padding-top:14px;
    padding-bottom:14px;
    padding-right:0px;
}

#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#nav ul li{
    margin-right:20px;
    display:inline;
}

#nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Let me know if this helps.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for taking the time but i'm using 2 different logos not just animating one. Your code is ideal if you're just animating the css of the logo but i need a way to stop any occurrence of both logos being displayed.